# Find label img from radio selection and apply to separate img src

Tags: javascript, css, forms

I'm looking for `JavaScript` that takes the `img src` from the `selected input` and applied it to the `img src` of a separate div, which I've created under `.selected-radio`.

I want the `img src` for `.selected-radio` to match the `selection` and the initial `checked`.

```css
#radios {
 display: flex;
 padding: 20px;
}
#radios label,
.selected-radio {
 display: block;
 height: 38px;
 width: 38px;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
}
#radios label + label {
 margin-left: 25px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
input[type="radio"] + span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 color: #b3cefb;
 border-radius: 50%;
 padding: 5px;
 transition: all 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
 border: 2px solid #4285f4;
}
```

```html
<div class="selected-radio"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5a985a90ec8f79000104514a_united-kingdom.svg">
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div id="radios">
  <label for="usa">
   <input type="radio" name="mode" id="usa" value="usa" checked/>
   <span><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5a2f052996bde90001f96632_united-states-of-america.svg"><span>
  </label>
  <label for="canada">
   <input type="radio" name="mode" id="canada" value="canada" />
   <span><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5a2cd7b0937442000184b147_canada.svg"><span>
  </label>
  <label for="uk">
   <input type="radio" name="mode" id="uk" value="uk" />
   <span><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5a985a90ec8f79000104514a_united-kingdom.svg"><span>
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ...and you haven't tried anything so far? I mean your request is as simple as it gets. Show some interest in solving the problem yourself and then we may be able to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with javascript.

I added a function, `changeImg`, and put some id's on `img`s.

Id's of the `img`'s  are in a specific form, starts with 'img-' and ends with the value of the related radiobutton.

```js
function changeImg(elm) {
  var val = elm.value;
  
  var img = document.getElementById('img-' + val);
  
  var src = img.src;
  
  var imgSelectedRadio = document.getElementById('img-selected-radio');
  
  imgSelectedRadio.src = src;
}
```

```css
#radios {
 display: flex;
 padding: 20px;
}
#radios label,
.selected-radio {
 display: block;
 height: 38px;
 width: 38px;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
}
#radios label + label {
 margin-left: 25px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
input[type="radio"] + span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 color: #b3cefb;
 border-radius: 50%;
 padding: 5px;
 transition: all 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
 border: 2px solid #4285f4;
}
```

```html
<div class="selected-radio"><img id="img-selected-radio" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5a985a90ec8f79000104514a_united-kingdom.svg">
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div id="radios">
  <label for="usa">
   <input type="radio" onchange="changeImg(this)" name="mode" id="usa" value="usa" checked/>
   <span><img id="img-usa" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5a2f052996bde90001f96632_united-states-of-america.svg"><span>
  </label>
  <label for="canada">
   <input type="radio" onchange="changeImg(this)"  name="mode" id="canada" value="canada" />
   <span><img id="img-canada" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5a2cd7b0937442000184b147_canada.svg"><span>
  </label>
  <label for="uk">
   <input type="radio" onchange="changeImg(this)"  name="mode" id="uk" value="uk" />
   <span><img id="img-uk" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5a985a90ec8f79000104514a_united-kingdom.svg"><span>
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Now I'm trying to figure out how I could use this same setup for applying the background color instead of the img src...